# Snapshot Firebase React native: "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an array of objects from firebase in realtime, however I am getting this warning, and it doesn't work properly when modifying firebase data in realtime.

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, yRIVsUeKnpcrpsft96YzOkeVKjD3. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

What am I doing wrong?

```
export const vendedoresCercanos = (lat, long, callback) => {let vendedores = []; db.collection("Usuarios")
.where("type", "==", "Vendedor")
.orderBy("rating", "desc")
.where("disponible", "==", true)
.onSnapshot(
  (docSnapshot) => {
    docSnapshot.forEach((docSnapshot) => {
      const restaurante = docSnapshot.data();
      restaurante.id = docSnapshot.id;
      if (
        getDistanciaMetros(
          lat,
          long,
          restaurante.latitude,
          restaurante.longitude
        ) > 1
      ) {
        vendedores.push(restaurante);
      }
    });
    callback(vendedores);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

};

**I assign the information obtained in a state inside a useEfect.**

```
useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  if (location) {
    vendedoresCercanos(location.latitude, location.longitude, (usuario) => {
      setcercanos(usuario);
    });
  }
})(); }, [location]);
useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {(async () => { if (location) {vendedoresCercanos(location.latitude,location.longitude,(usuario) => {setcercanos(usuario);});} })(); }, [location]));
```

what am I doing wrong?